# Plone: What is workflow of Plone to develop eggs?

Tags: plone

I am new in Plone and developing a new egg and unable to understand the workflow of Plone. My queries are as follows:

**1.** I am unable to understand how these folder structure are correlated to each other.

**/browser**

**/content**

**/profile**

**__init__.py**

**setuphandler.py**

**2**. When **__init__.py**, **setuphandler.py and all generic setup (XML)** files calls in project.

**3**. What is the use of Plone **portals** in plone site.

[image]

You can also **provide the link of website** which contains a good explaination of this.Thanks in advance for helping me. Hope it will useful for me.

Comment: Plone-docs and -training are very good resources, just couldn't find a compressed example for explaining basic add-on-structure, added one in SO-docs: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/plone/8751/create-add-on

Comment: And a verbose explanation of the overview: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/plone/8751/create-add-on/27287/a-tale-about-creating-a-plone-add-on Although this should probably be another chapter, not an example, hm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a big question, and you are asking for a big answer.

However, you are better off starting the [Plone Training](http://training.plone.org/5/)  (or choose [Plone 4 Training](http://training.plone.org/4/) if you prefer), and discovering the answers to these questions and more as you do so.

Trust that helps!

Comment: Also: the fact that you are asking for "what is `__init__.py`" probably means you need to read at least the Python tutorial: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/